# Azure web app unexpected crash

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, web

I have a web app which is running in Azure. When I try to debug it in VS, I can get as far as to var newResume = new Resume() {JobId = (int)jobid}; line (I get correct jobid), but then I get "server error" and page is redirected to error page. Everything works locally. What can be the problem? Thanks for your time

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int jobid)
{
    var newResume = new Resume() {JobId = jobid};
    return View(newResume);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. In the project file view was not configured to be added